# What is the difference between curl and wget?

Tags: utilities, wget, curl, download

I am keen to know the difference between `curl` and `wget`. Both are used to get files and documents but what the key difference between them.

Why are there two different programs?

Comment: Main difference is that wget is used to download things while curl is used to test communication by using a specific protocol.

Comment: An interesting fact about wget: > [Wget can be typed in using only the left hand on a qwerty keyboard!](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html)

Comment: From `curl` author: https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html

Comment: Maybe an interessting new alternative for the javascript guys reading this: https://httpie.io/ The `httpie` package is available on debian. And is a neat alternative to curl, that does a lot of helpfull things when working with REST APIs.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

The main differences are:

- `wget`'s major strong side compared to `curl` is its ability to download recursively.
- `wget` is command line only. There's no lib or anything, but `curl`'s features are powered by libcurl.
- `curl` supports `FTP`, `FTPS`, `GOPHER`, `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, `SCP`, `SFTP`, `TFTP`, `TELNET`, `DICT`, `LDAP`, `LDAPS`, `FILE`, `POP3`, `IMAP`, `SMTP`, `RTMP` and `RTSP`. `wget` supports `HTTP`, `HTTPS` and `FTP`.
- `curl` builds and runs on more platforms than `wget`.
- `wget` is released under a free software copyleft license (the GNU GPL). `curl` is released under a free software permissive license (a MIT derivate).
- `curl` offers upload and sending capabilities. `wget` only offers plain HTTP POST support.

You can see more details at the following link:

[curl vs Wget](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've been wondering about for a few hours. I used wget to do a recursive spider on a site, seems stalled on a page that has eleventy bazillion links on it. The reality is it's running at 100% CPU on one core. Was hoping that there was something better that does that newfangled multicore thing I've been hearing about.

Comment: One of the things `wget` does that is left out of this answer is http mirroring (or 'spidering') ability.  `curl` is very good at what it does, but it alone is not intended to be used to mirror a web site.

Comment: What about wput being an alias, supporting ftp.

Comment: These phrases have no sense: "and all copyrights are assigned to FSF", "is entirely stand-alone and independent with no organization parenting at all".
It's obvious that the author of cURL is the copyright owner of it. It's obvious that the author of wget is the copyright owner of it. But both are free as in freedom software. You can say instead that wget is under a copyleft license, and cURL under a permissive license.

Comment: @ValerioBozz: Actually no. Both curl and wget are community projects. With curl, each person owns the copyright to the code they contribute. With Wget, as with most other GNU programs, the various authors give away their copyrights to the FSF. That is, they don't own that code anymore. This is to allow the FSF to strictly enforce copyleft and to relicense the code if required.

Comment: the hyperlink in the end of the answer points to an article written by Daniel Sterberg, the author of `cURL`.

Comment: Another important point (IMHO), is that the mirroring capabilities of wget, include converting the files to adapt the links to their new location (and also, it can use time stamps to only download the files which changed since the last download).

Answer (score 136):

They were made for different purposes

- `wget` is a tool to download files from servers
- `curl` is a tool that let's you exchange requests/responses with a server

***wget***

Wget solely lets you download files from an `HTTP`/`HTTPS` or `FTP` server. You give it a link and it automatically downloads the file where the link points to. **It builds the request automatically.**

***curl***

Curl in contrast to wget lets you **build the request as you wish**. Combine that with the plethora of protocols supported - `FTP`, `FTPS`, `Gopher`, `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, `SCP`, `SFTP`, `TFTP`, `Telnet`, `DICT`, `LDAP`, `LDAPS`, `IMAP`, `POP3`, `SMTP`, `RTSP` and `URI` - and you get an amazing debugging tool (for testing protocols, testing server configurations, etc.).

As many already mentioned you can download a file with curl. True, but that is just an "extra". In practice, use CURL when you want to download a file via a protocol that wget doesn't support.

Comment: Actually `wget` also follows the redirect then saves the response unlike `curl`. Both can achieve the opposite to the default behaviour `wget -qO - http://google.co.uk/`  or `curl http://google.co.uk/ > index.html`

Comment: @mtm `curl http://google.co.uk/ > index.html` is not using an inbuilt functionality though. Anyway the main distinction is the **purpose** each tool was made for. There is not denying that tools evolve and many times deviate from their initial trajectory.

Comment: @mtm `curl http://google.co.uk -o index.html` would use curl's internals instead of shell output redirection with `>`.

Answer (score 25):

Actually, the major difference is that `curl` includes a library (`libcurl`), and that library is widely used by other applications.  `wget` is standalone.

Answer (score 22):

I did some performance tests with wget and curl, and the result is:

100 times tested average run time while downloading **1MB** file:

```
wget: 0.844s
cURL: 0.680s
```

100 times tested average run time while downloading **5MB** file:

```
wget: 1.075s
cURL: 0.863s
```

100 times tested average run time while downloading **10MB** file:

```
wget: 1.182s
cURL: 1.074s
```

Command size on the system:

```
wget: 371K
cURL: 182K
```

Comment: The benchmarks are reversed when dealing with small files. I had to replace curl with wget to speed up backend scripts that were frequently polling making web API calls with small responses to each. My guess startup time makes the difference.

I am also confused how your 10M file takes only 20% longer to download than 1M. There must be caching involved at some point. I am not convinced your benchmarks are valid. Also command size tells nothing about the size of all libraries it needs to load upon startup.

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ My RPi4 has 1000/1000 Mbit/s internet connection. I think the fast internet and slow hardware is the best combination to test the run time difference between wget and cURL commands.

Comment: Doesn't curl use a library? So there are additional packages that add to the total size.

Comment: `curl` links to `libcurl.so`. On my system: `wget` is 516K, `curl` is 255K, and `libcurl.so.4` is 658K. So `curl` is a total of 913K.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences(1. `curl` mainly reminds of communicating in various protocols, `wget` mainly reminds of downloading, 2. `curl` provides - and is based on - the `libcurl` library, and other softwares are able to use the same library as well, `wget` is standalone) have been mentioned in other answers, but here's also another difference worth emphasizing, explained in an example.

Another interesting feature of `curl` not possible with `wget` is communicating with UNIX sockets (**i.e., communication even without a network**).
For instance we can use `curl` to talk to [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) using its socket in `/var/run/docker.sock` to get a list of all pulled docker images in JSON format (useful for "programming", in contrast to the `docker images` CLI command which is good for "readability"):

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json | jq
```