# How to mirror/download a complete website with a browser?

Tags: linux, wget, browser

With wget you can mirror complete websites with: wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites website

Is there some equivalent way for using a browser like Firefox or Chromium and download the complete website (maybe with some scripting) ?
I'm wondering if e.g. all images would be saved and not just the preview. So if I click on an image in the offline version I get the larger version of the image. Or if I click a link I would get redirected to the local version of the link.

Comment: Modern websites are dynamic contents, I don't think you can mirror that

Comment: https://www.httrack.com/

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do that *any more*: there used to be plug-ins for FireFox that allowed you to do that, but they're not compatible with the latest version of FF.

Also: `wget` has a lot of options and implementing all those in a plugin is time-consuming for very few people using them, so it's not worth the development effort as the pros use [`wget` or `curl`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47434/what-is-the-difference-between-curl-and-wget) anyway...

Comment: curl doesn't support recursive downloads or mirroring. When it comes to mirroring a website, Wget is indeed the best, if not only, choice

Comment: @damir: yup, that's what my wget alias does and the curl.one doesn't: standard recursion for wget! **;-)**